# Dynamic table display on modal form

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, bootstrap-modal

I am targeting "model-body" section to load the dynamically created table in update.php, but when i click on the edit button,nothing is happens and then page becomes hanged.Can someone please advise what is missing ?
The code is simple, i want to post the update.php table in modal form

```
<div class="modal fade" id="Modal1" aria-labelledby="Modal-Edit Form" 
aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog">
<div class="modal-content">
<div class="modal-header">
<h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria- 
label="Close">
<span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
</button>
</div>
<div class="modal-body">
<table cellpadding="10px" width="100%" id="modal1">
</table>
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
</div>
</div>
</div>
$(document).on("click", ".edit-btn", function(e) {
$("#Modal1").toggle("show");
var peid = $(this).data("eid"); 
$.ajax({
url: "update.php",
type: "POST",
data:{
id: peid
},
success: function(data) {
$("#Modal1 table").html(data);
}
});
});
```

update.php

```
$sql = "select * FROM table1 WHERE pname='" .$search_value ."'";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql) or die("Query failed");
$output = "";
if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)
{
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
$output .= "<tr>
<td>Policy Name</td></br>
<td><input type='text' id='modal-name1' value='{$row["pname"]}'></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Source Address</td></br>
<td><input type='text' id='modal-src' value='{$row["src"]}'></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Destination Address</td></br>
<td><input type='text' id='modal-name' value='{$row["dst"]}'></td>  
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Ports</td></br>
<td><input type='text' id='modal-name' value='{$row["ports"]}'></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input type='submit' id='submit-btn-modal' value='Save'></td>
</tr>";
}
mysqli_close($conn);
echo $output;
}
else {
echo "<h2>No Record Found.</h2>";
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Do you see any errors in Console? Does your Network > Request look correct? Do you see a Response? I do not see any issues with the two scripts from first glance.

Comment: I suspect the issue is with the Bootstrap Modal. It's not shown in your example how the Button is configured. When I test here: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/g28wnyat/13/ the AJAX works yet the Modal is never shown.

Comment: you are  right,the problem was in the bootstrap but now i have made Modal form in css and its working. thank you very much for the reply.